# NullPointerException at ListView

Tags: android, listview, exception

I get an NPE at Line 29 (`private ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ScanList);`), but I guess this is because of the following line:

```
this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ScannerActivity.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
```

What belongs into "R.id.list_value" and "R.layout.row" is it a row.xml? I dont get what I have to write in there!

To know how the code works I paste a the relvant parts:

```
public class ScannerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private WifiManager wifi;
private ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ScanList);
private Button buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scannow_button);
private Switch enable;
private int size = 0;
private List<ScanResult> results;

private final String ITEM_KEY = "key";
private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private SimpleAdapter adapter;

/* Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);

    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    enable.setChecked(wifi.isWifiEnabled());
    enable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundbutton, boolean flag) {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(flag);
            if (flag) {
                arraylist.clear();
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonScan.setEnabled(true);
                wifi.startScan();
            } else {
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonScan.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
    this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ScannerActivity.this, arraylist, R.layout.activity_scan, new String[]{ITEM_KEY}, new int[]{R.id.ScanList});
    lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long id) {
            lv.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ScannerActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
            String mac = results.get(size).BSSID;
            myIntent.putExtra("mac", mac);
            ScannerActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });
```

This is my first ListView, so please help me :)

Comment: Initialize ListView & Button in onCreate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here :

```
private ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ScanList);
private Button buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scannow_button);
```

you are trying to initialize `ListView` and `Button` before setting layout for current Activity so you are getting NPE exception. move all initilzation inside onCreate method of Activity after calling `setContentView`  as:

```
    //...your code here...
private ListView lv;
private Button buttonScan;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ScanList);
    buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scannow_button);
    //...your code here...
```